# How to use os.system (or alternative) to remotely shutdown any system?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the call below to shut down my system, but I would like it to work on all major OS distro's. Is there a catch all shutdown command?

```
import os
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

Is there any other way to shutdown a machine remotely through python code?

Comment: There's no `/s` on anything [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) in particular for `shutdown`. Every operating system can invent their own semantics and even command-name. [BSD is slightly different](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?shutdown(8)).

Comment: This isn't really a Python question at all -- it's more a question about whether there's a portable equivalent to the `shutdown` command, which is applicable even without any software development going on.

Comment: Therefore my question remains, is there a portable python shutdown command? Thank you

Comment: No, there is not. You could write your own function that worked on a predefined set of OSs, though.

Answer (score 0):

For managing nodes remotely, ansible is a very nice tool, with gather facts you can get the current node os, then conditionally shut down accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Following function provides portable way of sending commands to remote host:

```
def run_shell_remote_command(remote_host, remote_cmd, pem_file=None, ignore_errors=False):
    remote_cmd = remote_cmd.split(' ')
    cmd = [SSH_PATH, '-o ConnectTimeout=30', '-o BatchMode=yes', '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no']
    if pem_file:
        cmd.extend(['-i', pem_file])
    cmd.extend([remote_host] + remote_cmd)
    print(f"SSH CMD: {cmd}")
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        if not ignore_errors:
            raise RuntimeError("%r failed, status code %s stdout %r stderr %r" % (
                remote_cmd, p.returncode, stdout, stderr))
    return stdout.strip()  # This is the stdout from the shell command
```

That way you can run any command on remote host, which are supported by remote OS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is portable.

Comment: It portable if you have sshd installed on your remote machine. Its now part of Windows components btw